# Sitecore 7.2 - Internal Links returning incorrect host names

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have 2 Sitecore sites with the same site tree (we'll call them SiteABC and SiteXYZ). Sometimes, in the Rich Text Editor for a page, there needs to be a link from one site's subpage to a subpage on the other. The problem I'm facing is that the Internal Links are not returning the correct host names.

UPDATE: I have fixed the internal link issue regarding linking a page on SiteXYZ to a page on SiteABC. See the updated Web.config code below.

```
<site name="siteabc" hostName="siteabc.local.com" targetHostName="siteabc.local.com:8080" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/siteabc" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0"
    xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="wwwsiteabc" hostName="www.siteabc.local.com" targetHostName="siteabc.local.com:8080" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/siteabc" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="false" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0"
    viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="wwwsitexyz" hostName="www.sitexyz.local.org" targetHostName="sitexyz.local.org" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/sitexyz" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0"
    viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="sitexyz" hostName="sitexyz.local.org" targetHostName="sitexyz.local.org" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/sitexyz" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0"
    xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

I am still having trouble with internal links to SiteXYZ from SiteABC. Even though I have set the targetHostName for SiteXYX to be sitexyz.local.org, there is still a problem with the url--8080 keeps being appended:

`sitexyz.local.org:8080/parentPage/childPage.aspx`

This is incorrect as it should be sitexyz.local.org--no 8080 attached.

Is there any way I can fix this by adjusting a setting in the Web.config file? I don't want to have to create some custom class to override anything -- I'm still learning Sitecore and have no idea how I would go about doing something like that :\ I'm assuming there is something in the Web.config I can change, though, just not sure what as I haven't dealt with this sort of issue before in Sitecore.

Comment: Have you tried set `targetHostName` to the site definition? See https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties.aspx

Comment: Setting the targetHostName for SiteABC worked, but it does not work for SiteXYZ. See my updated post for the details.

Comment: Try adding `port="80"` to the `SiteXYZ` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multisite environments, if you want to cross-link between the sites, always use `targetHostName` for every site definition. That tells Sitecore what should be the hostname of the generated urls, if the item belongs to given site.

And for the port problem, if `port` is not specified for the **target** site, Sitecore uses port number from your **current** site. That's why Sitecore adds `:8080` to your links. Just add `port="80"` to your `SiteXYZ` definition and the problem should be gone.

More documentation can be found in [site Attribute Properties](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties.aspx)
 article. For some reason it does not contain **port** information, but it's there in the `SiteInfo` class.